# ERROR [worker reload] [worker init] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Tags: nuxt.js, vitest

I installed Nuxt3 with vuetify and Vitest:

#### 1.install nuxt3

```
npx nuxi init [name-ap] //install nuxt3 app
cd name-app
npm i
npm i vuetify@next sass
```

#### 3. Create plugin for vuetify

1. create new folder: 'plugins' in app root folder
2. create new file: 'vuetify.ts' in plugins folder

```
//vuetify.ts

    import {createVuetify} from 'vuetify'
    import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
    import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

    export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
        const vuetify = createVuetify({
            components,
            directives
        
        })

        nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)

    })
```

#### 4. Install icon-set

1. Install the icon set

```
    npm i @mdi/font   // fontset that works well with vuetify
```

2. Open `nuxt.config.ts` and make these changes:

```
\\nuxt.config.ts

    export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass', '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css'],
    build: {
              transpile: ['vuetify']
           }
    })
```

#### 6. Vitest install

`npm install -D vitest`

And in `package.json` add scripts for vitest:

```
\\ package.json

    "scripts": {
        ...

        "test": "vitest --run --reporter verbose --globals",
        "test:watch": "vitest --reporter verbose --globals"
    }
```

And when I create my first test.file:

```
\\ hello.test.js

import { expect, test } from 'vitest'

test('should work as expected', () => {
  expect(Math.sqrt(4)).toBe(2)
})
```

and try to `npm run dev` my app I see this error:

```
 **ERROR**  [worker reload] [worker init] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')                                                               16:32:10

  at node_modules/vitest/dist/chunk-runtime-chain.f51aa930.js:2234:34
  at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:195:25)
  at async Promise.all (index 0)
  at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
  at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
  at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

This has to do with 'vitest'. It diappears when I remove the test:

```
  test('should work as expected', () => {
    expect(Math.sqrt(4)).toBe(2)
  })
```

from the testfile.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, do I need to add some code to nuxt.config.ts?

best regards, Martijn Dekker

Answer (score 0):

It seems that unit testing is not yet supported. But a Nuxt3 teammember is working on it and there is already a suggested experimenatl solution to try out. Did not work for me but maybe it will for you. See github: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/2465